# C++ unordered_map weird size allocation

Tags: c++, lock-free

I am experimenting with this code with a lockfree programming and running into weird problems.

This is a dinning philosophers problem, and I am trying to implement that in a lockfree way.

I am reserving the size of unordered_map and making sure that it is not relocating objs during runtime. But unfortunately what I see that during runtime size of `Philosopher::umap` is weirdly assigned, (in example below, I am restricting it to 10, but during runtime it is changing to 30-40). Can someone help me understand what is going on here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

class Eater {
public:
    virtual void Eating() = 0;
    ~Eater() {

    }
};

class Dreamer {
public:
    virtual void Dreaming() = 0;
    ~Dreamer() {}
};

class Gamer {
public:
    virtual void Gaming() = 0;
    ~Gamer() {
        
    }
};

class Philosopher : public Dreamer, public Eater {
private:
    const uint32_t id_;
public:
    static std::atomic<uint32_t> gen;
    static std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t>> umap;

    Philosopher()
        : id_(++gen) {
            umap.emplace(id_, std::make_tuple(0,0));
    }

    Philosopher(const Philosopher& that) : id_(that.id_) {
    }

    Philosopher(Philosopher&& that) : id_(that.id_) {
    }

    virtual void Eating() override {
        umap[id_] = std::make_tuple(1+std::get<0>(umap[id_]), std::get<1>(umap[id_])); // this is failing - despite, seperate thread working on separate memory location
    }

    virtual void Dreaming() override {
        umap[id_] = std::make_tuple(std::get<0>(umap.at(id_)), 1+std::get<1>(umap.at(id_))); // this is failing - despite, seperate thread working on separate memory location
    }

    ~Philosopher() {
    }
};
std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t>> Philosopher::umap;
std::atomic<uint32_t> Philosopher::gen(0u);

class Engine : public Gamer {
private:
    uint32_t m_count_philosophers_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> m_vthread_;
public:
    Engine(uint32_t n)
        : m_count_philosophers_(n) {
            m_vthread_.reserve(n);
    }
    virtual void Gaming() override {
        std::atomic<uint32_t> counter(0u);
        while(counter++ < m_count_philosophers_) {
            m_vthread_.emplace_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>([&]() mutable {
                                    Philosopher philosopher;
                                    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds;
                                    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                                    while(elapsed_seconds.count() < 2) {
                                        philosopher.Eating();
                                        philosopher.Dreaming();
                                        auto finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                                        elapsed_seconds = finish - start;
                                    }
                                 }));
        }

        for(auto &iter : m_vthread_) {
            iter->join();
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    auto N = 10u;

    Philosopher::umap.reserve(N); // there are no more than N elements in the unordered_map
    Engine eng(N);
    eng.Gaming();

    for (auto &i : Philosopher::umap)
    {
        std::cout << "phi: " << i.first << " eating: " << std::get<0>(i.second) << ", dreaming: " << std::get<1>(i.second) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are accessing the map from multiple threads with no synchronisation.

Comment: @MikeVine why that is a problem, each thread are accessing seperate locations in the map. there are no memory contentions.

Comment: I don't know about the solution to your problem, but one comment I'd make is that if you have virtual methods you should make destructors also virtual. This makes sure it gets cleaned up correctly if you allocate one of the classes polymorphically inside a smart pointer or use new somewhere and then destroy it.

Comment: You can access in multiple threads but you can't add items or remove items while other threads are accessing.

Comment: rehashing can occur even if the capacity doesn't change irrc

Comment: @kishoredbn see "https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety". Note that this doesn't cover being thread safe in your use case.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see what you are saying. can this be solved if I override the hashing function?

Comment: Pretty sure the choice to rehash comes from the container, not the hasher.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rehashing. It has to do with what you are allowed to do. See my link. You can "fix" your code by inserting an (empty) item into each slot in a thread safe manner. Then later you can access _different_ items in different threads safely.

Comment: So I did some changes in the code. Removed `Philosopher philosopher` out of thread lambda and moved it in the `Gaming()` method, and creating all philosophers obj together.
        `std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher(m_count_philosophers_);`. And this works fine. I am guessing adding elements in a lockfree way is not allowed on `unordered_map<>` container, even when the keys are guaranteed to be different.

Comment: @kishoredbn even if the keys are different their slot-assignments within the unordered_map’s internal array will sometimes be equal, at which point a secondary mechanism will be employed to handle the slot-collision; it is that code that will suffer from race conditions if access to the unordered_map is not serialized.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner got it. So I asked this question ^^^^ can this be solved by overriding the hash does that make any difference. I am guessing the answer is "No". May be because what hash-code gets allocated to which internal array memory also reshuffles?

Comment: @kishorwdbn I dont think so; unordered_map was never intended to be a lockless data structure, so if that’s what you need you should probably use something that was designed for that purpose.